# Collapsing element in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div >
 <div>
  <h3 style="display:inline-block;">Comments</h3>
  <button id="add_button" style="display:inline-block;margin-left:240px;" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="$('#add_button').hide()" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#comments">Add</button>
 </div>
 <div id="comments" class="collapse in">
  <textarea style="resize:none;width:90%;" class="input xlarge" rows="4" id="comment-box" name="comment-box" placeholder="Type your comment here..."></textarea>
  <button style="margin-right:30px;" id="submit_comment" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" name="submit_comment" type="submit" onClick="">Submit</button>
 </div>
</div>
```

So this my code. I have a collapsable element from bootstrap and I am trying to have it start off collapsed in the page but trying multiple different methods I can't. I've used a couple of jQuery commands like **hide()** and collapse but none of them seem to work. Any ideas on how to get this to work?

Comment: Get rid of the `in` class for the `div[id="comments"]` element

Comment: do you have bootstrapjs file included in the project

Comment: seems to be working here http://plnkr.co/edit/qd3nOg?p=preview

Comment: @ArunPJohny No it doesn't seem to be working there. But if you remove the `in` class, it does.

Comment: do you want it to be collapsed by default? then you need to remove the `in` class

Comment: @ArunPJohny your comment was what I needed to do although I had a friend who knew that also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply removing the `in` class from the `id='comments'` div as I've shown in this JSFiddle allows for the comments textarea to appear on clicking the `add` button:

http://jsfiddle.net/JHkHE/1/